# o que é o objeto clientcontext sharepoint?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estou com uma dúvida, já  pesquisei em alguns lugares mas não consigo entender que contexto é esse que a classe clientcontext instancia.

Estou usando no meu código passando uma URL (obviamente)
Sei que essa classe cria um contexto da pagina que foi passada por parametro
mas gostaria de uma definição mais técnica, oque essa classe faz nos bastidores.

```
using(var clientContext = this.clienteContext("URL"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá!

o Clientcontext é o contexto onde seu código será executado, ou seja, a partir dele é onde você consegue acessar os objetos do SharePoint para recuperar o site atual, usuário atual, listas e itens do SharePoint.

Por exemplo, para recuperarmos o site atual do contexto onde nosso código está sendo executado, vamos utilizar o clientContext.Web. Para recuperarmos uma determinada lista do nosso portal, vamos utilizar o clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Nome da Lista")